# Retrieving Client Information on the Server-Side via WCF

Tags: wcf, rest

I'm using WCF to build some REST-based services. These services will be connected to via client-side Silverlight and Java applications. I would like to know some information about the requester. My question is, what class exposes requester information in WCF and how do I access it?

I know in ASP.NET I can use HttpRequest. I can even get more details via the HttpRequest.Browser property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just read about this:

> WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest

where you should info about the clinet and the http request headers.

Hope it helps.